# How do I show a specific view for the users resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise

I have two models:

```
User
has_many :prices

Price
belongs_to :users
```

I want to show the view like this:

```
<% show this view if price belongs to current user %>
 <div> Price of Current User </div>
<% end %>
```

How would I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you question, but doesn't `<%= current_user.prices %>` cover you?

Comment: @shuriu I changed up my question to make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the association in the Price model should be

```
belongs_to :user #not users
```

Second of all, I'm still not sure if I understand the question, but I'll give you my 2 cents:

If you simply want to show the current user's prices in your view:

```
<% current_user.prices.each do |price| %>
  <div><%= price %></div>
<% end %>
```

This will output each user's price.

If you're looping through all of your prices, and want to display something when a price belongs to the user you could use something like:

```
<% @prices.each do |price| %>
  <div><%= price %>
    <% if price.user == current_user %>
    <span> << out of all the prices, this is yours</span>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Assuming you have @prices (@prices = Price.all), and current_user defined in your controller, this piece of code loops through all the prices and adds a span when the price belongs to the current user.

Hope this helps you.. Also, have a look at [this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) about associations, and what you can do with them.

Comment: I should've been more clear. The view was using the `show action` so I would only see one price per page. Either way, it solved my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` in the conditional should be `==`.